# i am not able to figure out the problem due to which i can't upload my sketch to nano

Tags: arduino-nano

this is the error code (it is new from the previous time i posted)

i am using the hourly build for this and not the Beta

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6e
```

[image]

this is the info of the loader and board i am using

Comment: the code has no problems but idk what is avrdude

Comment: Looks like your installation is incomplete. Make sure your core is up to date in the boards manager. Try reinstalling the core.

Comment: it is up to date i even checked it even the conf file it there but it shows can't open config file and then path name then shows no such directory or file

Comment: Them maybe you have a permissions problem. Are you using the app store version on Windows 10 s?

Comment: yes i am using the store version

Comment: Don't. It's broken. Download the version form the Arduino website.

Comment: k thx for the solution

Comment: Uninstall the IDE. Delete all the support files. Download the IDE. Update the core.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea - try using Windows Filemanager to navigate down through the folder path shown in the error message and see if the avrdude.conf file exists in the specified place. this probably will not solve your problem but it might help to understand what is happening. Good luck - Bob

Answer (score 0):

I am just taking a guess as I operate on Linux. I would suggest go to tools menu and see if the correct board is selected. I would venture to guess it is not set for nano. Mine gives me two choices new and old. Try one and if it does not work try the other. Be sure your Baud is set correctly.